# What is the easiest way to check for record with two criteria, insert if it doesn't exist, if one or multiple exist, update them all

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm having a damned time doing a query.

There's a field of building_id, username and correct.

We need to see if any records exist for a user and a particular building (because they can only have one vote).

If it doesn't exist, we need to insert a new record with building_id, username and correct.

If it does exist, we need to find the record with building_id and username and update correct to be the new vote.

I've been playing with save, update, get_or_create and they all keep popping up errors. How would this be done in MongoEngine?

Comment: what are the types of fields you are talking about?  Can you include a sample document please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple update, setting upsert and multiple to true:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

the syntax is as following:

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   { upsert: <boolean>, multi: <boolean> }
)
```

Regarding the check for two criteria, your query can contain as many as you want.

I don't know your collections, but maybe:

```
db.yourCollection.update({"user": "someUser", "buildindId": "someBuildingId"}, {"correct": "your correction"}, {upsert: true, multi: true})
```